# sqlsrv_fetch_array returning NULL

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have an issue where using sqlsrv_fetch_array is returning NULL. I am trying to do a simple query on a view in MS SQL that I have verified in SQL Server Management Studio provides results.

I am running PHP 7.4.4 on Windows Server 2016 x64, with version 5.8 of the PHP SQL drivers and 17.5.2.1 of the ODBC driver.

Similar queries are being run on 4 other views within this database and all work fine. Below is the code I'm testing:

```
<?php

include("../mscon.php");

$msConnInfo = array( "Database"=>"XYZ", "UID"=>"username", "PWD"=>"password");

$msConn = sqlsrv_connect( $msServerName, $msConnInfo);

if($msConn)
{
    //echo "Connection established.\n";
}
else
{
    //echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM Public_Web";

$result = sqlsrv_query($msConn, $query, array(), array( "Scrollable" => 'static' )) or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

if ($result === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
else
    echo "We good fam, no errors<br/>\n";

var_dump($result);

if(sqlsrv_has_rows($result))
{
    echo "<br/>Rows exist<br/>\n";
    $numRows = sqlsrv_num_rows($result);

    echo "There are $numRows rows<br/>\n";

    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result));
    {
        var_dump($row);
    }
}
else
{
    echo "no results were found<br/>\n";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $result);
sqlsrv_close($msConn);

?>
```

The above code outputs lets me know that there are no errors and that 1493 rows exist in the view. But when I do a var_dump on $row it outputs NULL. All of the fields in the view I'm trying to access are varchar and there are only 7 fields total.

I have tried just grabbing one field in my query instead of all fields, no change in results. It seems like I have tried all possible troubleshooting methods.

Anything you can think of would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting a different output with a statement like `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Public_Web`?

Comment: @Zhorov No change, other than it's now reporting that I have 1 row selected instead of 1493 rows. Var_dump still says that $row is NULL.

Comment: It's strange. Your code is correct and I'm not able to reproduce this issue. Is it possible to SELECT from a view, defined in a different database?

Comment: @Zhorov Yes, other views in this database work just fine. Other views in other databases also work. The only view I'm having an issue with is this one. I've checked permissions on it, they are the same as my other views.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. We ended up deleting the view in SQL and recreating it. No idea why it wasn't working properly.